# Webpack static site build

Tags: javascript, build, webpack

My site is a HTML static site which includes a several JS files. I want to use Webpack only to help me build (combine, uglify, minimize) JS files . I would then host my index.html on S3 and serve it through a cloudfront so I will not have any backend.

I have `index.html`, `style.css` and few JavaScript files. When I build with `webpack`, all `.js` files are built into `bundle-script.js`. and if I open site locally, `index.html` file can't access functions from `bundle-script.js`.
I have tried with `"webpack -p"`, but without success. 
From what I am seeing it seems like Webpack requires to have a nodejs server running in the background probably to support a hot-reload feature.

In `package.json` build is set to webpack. `"build": "webpack"`

Here is my `webpack.config.js`

Am I having the right approach? How can I configure a webpack to do just a static built for me?

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
const StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin = require('static-site-generator-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  target: 'web',
  entry: "./src/home.js",

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle-script.js'
  },

  module: 
  {
    rules: [
    // CSS: scss, csss
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: "css-loader"
        })
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("style.css"),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
          'NODE_ENV': `"production"`
      }
    }),
    new StaticSiteGeneratorPlugin({
      crawl: true
    })
  ]

};

   module.exports = config;
```

Comment: your starting page is home.js so all build code are make home.js file or any other?

Comment: home.js is starting page, and all .js files are required with require method e.g.  require("./search");